# How do I extract values from columns of only specified rows?

Tags: python, row

I have the following table in my python:

| ID | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jacob | 14 |
| 2 | Phil | 21 |
| 3 | Emil | 25 |
| 4 | Raj | 23 |

How do I print column three (age) from the table but only for rows that have the element in column one that is also present in list `y=[4,5,2,6]`. So in this case, we are looking for the age for ID 2 and 4. I am a newbie in python, so any advice helps.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
C1= list(Table["ID"])
x= (list(set(C1).intersection(y)))
for x in Table["ID"]:
    print Table["age"]
```

I am sure that I am doing the loop wrong at the end, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your data in dataframe format?

Then instead of going through a loop, you can use the code below.

```
y=[4, 5, 2, 6]
Table[Table['ID'].isin(y)]['age']
```

`Table[Table['ID'].isin(y)]` will select the rows in `y`